# Magento 2 Insurance on Cart Page

Tags: magento2

I want to add functionality for applying insurance on cart page like when customer check the "Insurance" checkbox then some defined Insurance amount will apply to cart and will show in right hand summary section and vice versa if customer unchecked it then Insurance amount will remove from the section.Can anybody help me on it.

[image: Insurance]

Comment: Add it as custom option in the product, remove product programatically and add again the product to cart. Or just try to update it. Use standard code. Use same code that is triggered by add to cart button on product page (the action). You'll have to have params sent to add to cart (like custom option ids and other).

Comment: I tried with calling custom controller from cart page for handling the insurance value and set it on quote object but its not working.